# Random value generator for same variable in json file

Tags: scala, gatling

Is there a way to generate random values inside the session for the same parameter.

Ex json file-

```
{
    "age": "${age}"
},
{
    "age": "${age}"
}

val ageFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map ("age" -> (0 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100 - 0) + 1).toString ()))
val scn = scenario("test")
   .exec(feed(ageFeeder))
   .exec(session => {
// code to read the file using ElFileBody which replaces ${age} with randomly generated age
})
```

I want to generate random values for the number of times we are calling ${age} in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `feed` instruction should not be in one exec I think.
Try:

`.feed(ageFeeder)
.exec(session => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you won't know until execution how many ${age} values you need to replace, you might be better not using a feeder.

instead, you could have a session variable that's a list of all possible numbers, then use the gatling EL to randomly index into that list.

so at the top of your file

```
val ages: Seq[Int] = (1 to 100).toSeq
```

then at the start of your scenario, persist this list into the session

```
exec(session => session.set("ages", ages))
```

and then in your file, rather than ${ages} you can use

```
"${ages.random()}"
```